Failed to scrape a certain field from the results populated upon initiating a search using an account number on a website
When I initiate a search on this website using this account number 0523620090003, I can see relevant details concerning the account in the results. I've created a script using the requests module to scrape the two portions of the results: account details and fiduciary. I can already scrape the account details located at the top left. However, I can't parse the information related to Fiduciary, which is located in the middle of the right corner.
import requests
from pprint import pprint

link = 'https://arcweb.hcad.org/server/rest/services/public/public_query/MapServer/0/query'

params = {
    'f': 'json',
    'distance': 2,
    'outFields': '*',
    'outSR': '102100',
    'spatialRel': 'esriSpatialRelIntersects',
    'units': 'esriSRUnit_StatuteMile',
    'where': "HCAD_NUM = '0523620090003'",
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    res = s.get(link,params=params)
    pprint(res.json()['features'][0]['attributes'])


How can I scrape the fiduciary-related information from the website using the requests module?


Is it just me or does the website hardly work and/or need a US IP?

@baduker It's you. Works fine from UK (even without explicit headers)

The website depends heavily on JavaScript. You could use selenium to initiate the search then subsequently scrape the information you need from the page that gets loaded by the search

As suggested in the comments you might find it useful to automate your interaction with the site using Selenium.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import time

ACCOUNT_NUMBER = "0523620090003"

URL = "https://hcad.org/property-search/property-search"

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", options=options)

driver.get(URL)

# Change focus to <iframe>.
iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe")))
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

# Locate the <input> field.
input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[type="search"]')))

# Insert search term.
input.send_keys(ACCOUNT_NUMBER)
time.sleep(2)

# Trigger search.
button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".input-group-append button")
button.click()

time.sleep(5)

# Find first search result and click.
row = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr.resulttr.odd")))

row.click()

time.sleep(5)

# Get fiduciary details.
fiduciary = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "i.fa-person-walking-luggage")))
details = fiduciary.find_element(By.XPATH, './../following-sibling::*[1]')
print(details.text)

driver.close()

I'm using a remote instance of Selenium. You can replace the call to webdriver.Remote() with this:
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

Output from the fiduciary part of the page:
BETTENCOURT TAX ADVISORS LLC - 05082

